# when I am going to open my website , it displaying Internal Server Error

Tags: web-services, .htaccess

when I am going to open my website , it displaying Internal Server Error
Error message is

Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: **More information about this error may be available in the server error log.** Why not check server log and report it here.

Comment: error Premature end of script headers: index.php

Comment: That means error is in your `index.php` code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you need to clarify to make it easier for folks to help:

1. Your website address
2. Did you make any changes just before this error showed up?
3. Your website's platform (wordpress, drupal, simple html)
4. Hosting provider

Comment: error
Premature end of script headers: index.php
Platform CI